# Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL i have created one table in that i need to delete duplicate entry data.

can any one help me regarding this, 6 lake  data is there in that so many repeat data is there.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt that SQL to your table:

```
DELETE u1 FROM oc_product u1, oc_product u2 WHERE u1.product_id < u2.product_id AND u1.sku = u2.sku;
```